# How to add XML datasource Summary Grid?

Tags: jquery, sencha-touch, extjs

I am new to EXT.js and trying to use XML feed instead of an array is there any example on how to add xml feed to this instead of array to this "Summary Grid Example" . http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/grid/group-summary-grid.html

And I want be broken up into groups as in the example..How can I go about adding xml feed to replace the arrays?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your link is broken, can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

XML or Arrays as the data type that feeds a grid is really a property of the grid's store.  That data is given to the grid as records of the store, so its just the store's reader that cares about the incoming data type.  Therefore, you should be able to use this example to put XML data in a store, which can be used by a grid:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/grid/xml-grid.html